# How to open a child Activity of ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity, activitygroup

How to open a child `Activity` of `ActivityGroup` in Tab. I want to open a child activity from a status bar notification with Tab. I called activity directly but tabs are not visible. Anyone knows how to open an `Activity` of `ActivityGroup`.

Comment: Are you using custom tab

Comment: yes. i am using custom tab.

Comment: yup... I tried your solution as u suggested but not getting my solution...

Comment: you can accept the answer if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as reference, this will help you to resolve your issue.Here calling child activity explained beautifully.

http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

**Below is the answer of your question if you dont want go with that detailed URL**

Create the

`ArrayList<String> mIdList = new ArrayList<String>` in the `onCreate()` of ActivityGroup class.

**NOTE:**
 This mIdList helps you when you will come back to previous activity.

Create a method in your class which extends **ActivityGroup** like this:

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {   
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }
```

And In your main class which extends **Activity** do this:

```
Intent goOrderScreenActivity = new Intent(getParent(), CustomerInfoActivity.class);
            goOrderScreenActivity.putExtra("Flag", 1);
            **YourClassObjectWhichExtendsACtivityGroup** parentActivity = (YourClassObjectWhichExtendsACtivityGroup)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("YOUR_ID", goOrderScreenActivity);
```

Comment: I am calling child activity of activityGroup from "onClick" of status bar notification.

Comment: follow the URL I mentioned in my answer. No matter from where you are calling your child activity.Only matters the way and logic you are using for this

Comment: and how would handle `onBackPressed` on your `ActivityGroup`